Obtain Keycloak attributes from WSO2 ApiManager
Im trying to create an API in wso2 using Keycloak as an identity provider. I have some paths that after authentication need to access the user attributes in keycloak before the request is sent to my backend. For example:

Authenticate to keycloak using email and token at url GET https://whatever.com/getlist4user
If successful get attribute uuid for the user from keycloak
Transform the request to https://whatever.com/list/{uuid}

I'm using WSO2 Api Manager 4.3.0 with docker.
I don’t even know how to approach this issue. Until now, I’ve been using Kong API Manager with a custom plugin we developed in Python. I don’t know if I can take the same approach with WSO2. Some guidance would be appreciated.

You can use the API policy feature to implement a custom policy for any processing needs. For details on how to create a custom API policy, you can refer to the official documentation here: Create API Policy.
Additionally, you can deploy a custom class mediator to invoke an external service and handle the specific task you need. For guidance on creating and applying a class mediator within an API policy, you can check out this example: Using a Custom Mediator in WSO2 API Manager.
